# How to copy all files from one folder to another folder in the same S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to **copy all files from one folder to another folder** in the s3 bucket. I see a lot of examples for moving from one bucket to another but not from one folder to another.

from the examples I have seen online, I have written the following code.

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
src = 'old_folder'
dest = 'new_folder'

for key in s3_resource.list_objects(Bucket=config.S3_BUCKET)['Contents']:
    files = key['Key']
    copy_source = {'Bucket': config.S3_BUCKET, 'Key': f'{src}/{files}'}
    s3_resource.meta.client.copy(
        copy_source, f'{config.S3_BUCKET}/{dest}/', f'{src}/{files}')
```

however, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'list_objects'
```

for the following line: `for key in s3_resource.list_objects(Bucket=config.S3_BUCKET)['Contents']:`

I believe I am getting the error because I am using `boto3.resource(s3)` instead of `boto3.client(s3)` however the examples I have seen online seem to be using `boto3.resource(s3)` to move files from one bucket to another.

What is the correct approach to take to move all files from one folder to another folder in the same bucket in s3 using python?

Comment: Your code is not even a  valid python code. So its difficult to speculate what's wrong with it.

Comment: sorry, made it valid python code now @Marcin

Comment: How many objects do you have? Your code, even if fixed, does not do any pagination, thus its suited for copping only small number of files.

Comment: it could be a couple of 100 files

Comment: Do you mind if we can use command line libraries which will work seamless in this  situation ? Because for this scneario I would have chosen `s5cmd` library that gives `cp` command which can copy files from one folder to another with just one command and performance is 80 times more than `aws` cli

Comment: https://github.com/peak/s5cmd#copy-objects-from-s3-to-s3 just checkout this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code and also added pagination. Please have a look at it:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

src = 'old_folder'
dest = 'new_folder'

paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects')

operation_parameters = {'Bucket': config.S3_BUCKET,
                        'Prefix': src}

page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)

for page in page_iterator:
    for obj in page['Contents']:
        file = obj['Key']
        #print(file)    
        dest_key = file.replace(src, dest)
        #print("dest_key)
        s3.copy_object(Bucket=config.S3_BUCKET, 
                       CopySource=f'/{config.S3_BUCKET}/{file}', 
                       Key=dest_key)
```

Comment: getting the following error ```AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_paginator'``` @Marcin

Comment: Sorry for deleting it. The reason it wasn't working was that I had to use `boto3.client` instead of `boto3.resource`. If you could update your answer I can mark it as the accepted answer.